# converting date time to 24 hour format

Tags: java, datetime

The time I get from the server is like  `Jul 27, 2011 8:35:29 AM`.

I want to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

I also want the converted time to be in 24 hour format. Can any one give solution to this problem. The output I want to get is like `2011-07-27 08:35:29`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try this:

```
String dateStr = "Jul 27, 2011 8:35:29 AM";
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (date != null) {
    String formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to convert 2:46 PM to 14:46 with this code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1930402 you can do this by changing your read format to `hh:mm a` - your input ignores the seconds (is a guess).

Comment: when we have  aa in the format makesure that hh is small case else it should  be in capitol

Comment: Very small and hard to identify if you are not aware with pattern of date format. For me, it is just a change of `hh` to `HH` and problem solved!

Answer (score 211):

H vs h is difference between 24 hour vs 12 hour format.

Comment: For newbie:

`DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");`

Answer (score 107):

```
kk = Hours in 1-24 format
hh= hours in 1-12 format
KK= hours in 0-11 format
HH= hours in 0-23 format
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Date date=new Date("12/12/11 8:22:09 PM");    
System.out.println("Time in 24Hours ="+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date));
```

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at Java date formatting, in particular [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). There's some examples here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html - but you can also find a lot more with a quick google.

Answer (score 4):

I am taking an example of date given below and print two different format of dates according to your requirements.

```
String date="01/10/2014 05:54:00 PM";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa",Locale.getDefault());

try {
            Log.i("",""+new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(date)));

            Log.i("",""+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(date)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you still have any query, Please respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date date = new Date();
    Date date2 = new Date("2014/08/06 15:59:48");

    String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    String anyDate = dateFormat.format(date2).toString();

    System.out.println(currentDate);
    System.out.println(anyDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // This is how to get today's date in Java
    Date today = new Date();

    //If you print Date, you will get un formatted output
    System.out.println("Today is : " + today);

    //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date);

    //Another Example of formatting Date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
    DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : " + date);

    //formatting Date with time information
    DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS");
    date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : " + date);

    //SimpleDateFormat example - Date with timezone information
    DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS Z");
    date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : " + date);

} 

}
```

Output:

Today is : Fri Nov 02 16:11:27 IST 2012

Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : 02-11-2012

Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : 02/11/12

Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : 02-11-12:16:11:316

Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : 02-11-12:16:11:316 +0530

Answer (score 2):

IN two lines:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",Locale.getDefault());
        FAJR = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse("8:35 PM");
```

Answer (score 1):

just a tip,

try to use JodaTime instead of java,util.Date
it is much more powerfull and it has a method
toString("") that you can pass the format you want like
toString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

With Calendar it works as follows:

```
    //create first Calendar object
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15); // 3 PM
    // the same is
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM); // choose PM mode
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3); // 3 PM

    System.out.println( calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) ); // AM_PM format
    System.out.println( calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ); // 0-23 format
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that uses JODA.

Input example is  `07/20/2015 01:46:34.436 AM`

```
public static String get24HourFormat(String dateString){
        Date date = new Date();
        DateTime date1=new DateTime();

        //  String date="";
        int hour=0;
        //int year=0;
        if(dateString!=null){

            try {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa");
                DateTimeFormatter output = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("kk");

                date1=formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);
                hour=date1.getHourOfDay();
                System.out.println(output.print(date1));
                //  System.out.println(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return hour+"";
    }
```