# Date Conversion not giving 24 hour format

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a `string ="02/07/2015 5:10 PM";`

I need a string date with format as: `2015-02-07 17:10:00;`

How can i achieve this?

I have tried with:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
Date datepicker1 = dateFormat.parse(datetime1);
```

Then

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
String datetimepicker1 = dateFormat1.format(datepicker1);
```

But finally I get is: `2015-02-08 05:10:00` and I need `2015-02-08 17:10:00`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting date time to 24 hour format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842245/converting-date-time-to-24-hour-format)

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning, you have to add the `a` letter to the pattern (which stands for `AM/PM`) and change `HH` to `h`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
```

Comment: @UdayKhatry, you are supposed to accept answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateStr = "02/07/2015 5:10 PM";
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa");
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try
{
    date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );
}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
if( date != null )
{
    String formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
}
```