# Parse String to Hours in CSV data

Tags: java

I have been trying to parse the String I got from the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file and convert the column "start" to hour. Here is my code:

```
public class BeerSong {


    private static final String csvFileName = "HourList201403.csv";
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, java.text.ParseException {        

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
        List<String[]>allLine = csvReader.readAll();

        SimpleDateFormat start = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int startH;
        Date startHour;
        for (String[] line : allLine) {
            startHour=start.parse(line[3]);
            calendar.setTime(startHour);
            startH = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            System.out.println(line[3]+", "+line[4]);
            System.out.println("Work: "+startH);            
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run, it outputs an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Start"

So, what am I doing wrong here and how to fix this ?

The CSV format is like this, it has a lot rows so I put some here:

```
Person Name, Person ID, Date, Start, End
Scott Scala, 2, 2.3.2014, 6:00, 14:00
Janet Java, 1, 3.3.2014, 9:30, 17:00
Scott Scala, 2, 3.3.2014, 8:15, 16:00
Larry Lolcode, 3, 3.3.2014, 18:00, 19:00
```

Comment: You're probably parsing the header of your csv. Maybe skip a row?

Comment: @Mena: Hi, how can I skip the first row as I am reading all of them at once ?

Comment: FYI, the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) project is a handy library that takes all the bother out of parsing CSV files (and other such delimited text files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run through all of the parsed lines in your loop. The first line is:
`Person Name, Person ID, Date, Start, End` . So the 4th item which you want to read out with: 
`startHour=start.parse(line[3]);` is `Start`. I think you have to skip the first line in your loop with:

`for(int i = 1; i < allLine.size(); i++){
 String[] line = allLine.get(i);`

Comment: Hi, it seems that String[] line = allLine[i] get error, so I use the allLine.get(i) and it works

Comment: and there is one problem I notice, in the file, there are some row that the hour is like 14:00 16:00, but when I convert them, it become 2 and 4. How can I keep the 14 and 16 ?

Comment: H vs h is difference between 24 hour vs 12 hour format. HH is the format for 24 hours and 12 for am and pm. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842245/converting-date-time-to-24-hour-format)

Comment: and if you dont mind, there is some row that the end is in the next day, so when I calculate the working duration between start and end, it returns negative number. And for some row, the start is 14h30 and end is 16h00. It should be 1h30 duration, but I got 2h. Is there any way to fix it ? I tried getting the minutes out from the string and fix some, but that's no good.

Comment: if you like you can have a look at [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which provides easy utils to do this tasks you are searching for.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.text.ParseException` is thrown on attempting to parse the string "Start" as a `Date`.

Clearly that's the header of your spreadsheet, so you should skip the first row (note index 1 here):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < allLine.size(); i++) {
```

Note that you'll need the rest of the fields in your column 3 to consistently be of format `HH:mm`, i.e. not empty, etc.

The trick here is to either use fast-enumeration and skipping the first line, or as I display above, use an `int`-based iteration starting at index `1` (collections are 0-based, so that'll skip the first item).