# Populating EditText with Date from CalendarView and Time from TimePicker

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to build an Android Application, I have one Activity which has 2 EditTexts and when I click on them, they will redirect me to the other activity which I will then select a date from CalendarView and time from TimePicker. Afterwards, I will click on Done and it will redirect me back to the previous Activity with the EditText filled.

Now, my question is, how do I populate the EditText with the date and time selected from the CalendarView and TimePicker in dd/MMM/yyyy and 24hr format??
I tried using Intent but I don't know how to code in.

Here's my partial code:

```
public class RentStartActivity extends Activity {
CalendarView calendar1;
TimePicker time1;
Button btnCancel1, btnDone1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rent_start);
    btnCancel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1);
    btnCancel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent cancel = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(cancel);
        }
    });

    btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
    btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent done = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            done.putExtra("Date1", calendar1.getDate());
            done.putExtra("Time", time1.getDrawingTime());
            startActivity(done);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Firstly confirm that Date and Time values getting correctly. After that in your SearchActivity get data using intent.                                            
String date= getIntent().getStringExtra("Date1");                                                                     String time= getIntent().getStringExtra("Time");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()`
in your SearchActivity:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RentStartActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

in your RentStartActivity:

```
btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent done = new Intent();
        done.putExtra("Date1", calendar1.getDate());
        done.putExtra("Time", time1.getDrawingTime());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,done);
        startActivity(done);
        finish();
    }
});
```

and get the data in SearchActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String date = data.getStringExtra("Date1");
            String time = data.getStringExtra("Time");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

To format date time You can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842245/converting-date-time-to-24-hour-format).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **startActivityForResult**() and **onActivityResult()** to send data between activities.

Check out this links:
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html