# Date changing from one format to another format

Tags: java

I am trying to parse the date from one format to another format, but getting the parse exception. Please help me out on this issue.

```
String Orgdate= "2016-11-14T11:12:13";
java.util.Date tardate = null;


SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS");//Exception is in this line.
    try {
        targetdateformat  = dateFormat2.parse(Orgdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above code giving me date but different format,i am looking for date like below mention.

```
('14/11/2016 11:12:13')
```

Time format is 24 Hrs.

Comment: Presumably this is Java, but without a java tag on the question it's unlikely to be answered.

Comment: Yes mark,this is java question only,but unfortunately i was added windows tag.i changed to java tag now.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string

Comment: see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565579/5456789

Answer (score 0):

why not just do a simple hardcode to get the format you would like. For example...

```
            String date = "2016-11-14T11:12:13";

            String newDate = date.charAt(8) + "" + date.charAt(9) + "/" +
                             date.charAt(5) + "" + date.charAt(6) + "/" +
                             date.substring(0, 4) + " " +  date.substring(11, 19);

            System.out.println(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `parse` to `Date` then `format` the date string to convert it into another format

```
    String Orgdate= "2016-11-14T11:12:13";
    java.util.Date tardate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            tardate = dateFormat2.parse(Orgdate);
            System.out.println(tardate); // Mon Nov 14 11:12:13 UTC 2016
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(tardate);
        System.out.println(formatted); 14/11/2016 11:12:13
```

If you are using `Java8` you can try below

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11-14T11:12:13", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
String formattedDate = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); // 14/11/2016 11:12:13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date a = sdf.parse("2016-08-12T08:29:47");
        sdf.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf.toPattern()); // to see if new pattern applied 
        System.out.println(sdf.format(a)); // get output in desired format
```